# 2 column layout and full page width subtitles

Tags: layout

I have a two column layout for a document I am working in. The client wants subtitles to be full page width (not only one column as normal, see attachment). Is it good practice to let the subtitles go full page width? I am not confortable. How can I theoretically explain it to customer?
[image: the subtitle should fill two columns (whole page width]

[image: More problematic for one column subtitles are cases like this. What is recommended?]

Comment: Generally, I’d say no. Not if they’re generally as frequent as here (about two per page, not counting illustrations). I take it higher-level headers (5 or 5.1 and 5.2) do span the columns? And if they’re talking about the level-4 headers (a, b, etc.), then definitely no. That would look horrible!

Comment: Not sure there's enough info to go on here. If you are referring to the `5.2.2`, and `5.2.3` headers.. I can see them being full width to visually break things a bit.